# Date Format in Power BI Hierarchical Slicer

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, powerbi

I have a `Power BI` file that connects to a data model via `SSAS`. The data model origin is a `SQL Server` view with some computed columns added in via `SSAS`.

One of the visualisations is a `Hierarchical Slicer` that shows dates. The field is not one of the computed `SSAS` columns. It displays in DD/MM/YYYY format but when I place the file on a `Power BI Report Server` the format is Americanised to MM/DD/YYYY. I want it to be **DD/MM/YYYY**.

The same field is used to populate a table visualisation but in there it remains DD/MM/YYYY. Just the slicer is affected.

This blog https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/date-format-in-slicer/td-p/215627 seemed to have the answer I needed but these settings were already applied and still the slicer shows MM/DD/YYYY.

Its not a problem when I open the pbix file locally; there, the slicer shows the dates as DD/MM/YYYY, its just when its on the server. The same problem persists in Test and Production and I have checked those settings and they are as the blog indicates. Other blogs identify this with the slicers but do not present a  real solution as its not seen as a problem in those topics.

I've only spent a month working with `Power BI` so have no real experience to draw upon. I know that `SQL Server` defaults to American English when connecting to a database and I have changed that to British English but still the same problem. How do I get the slicer showing as DD/MM/YYYY as in my local copy?

Answer (score 2):

Select the Date column and then go to the Modeling tab and change Format to whatever Date format you want.

[image: Power Bi Date Format]

OR

You can create a calculated column using the FORMAT method in DAX to convert date format as you want. 
See reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx

Comment: This option isn't avilable to me, all those options on the Ribbon apart from New Measures are greyed out. I suspect its because my data model comes from SSAS. I can look at making those date format changes there perhaps...

Comment: Have you tried refresh? This may activate options in your ribbon

Comment: Yes, but they remain greyed out. I think I will have to use an equivalent method like you suggest in SSAS.

Comment: Or you can use FORMAT function in DAX. See answer above.

Comment: Can't do that either because I am using it in DirectQuery mode. This says the FORMAT function won't work in this mode <https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634924.aspx>. Appreciate the suggestions though, am learning through these pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is missing the formatting in their recent releases. However, the below solution works for me:

Create a Calculated Column ref. the original Date column and apply "Short Date" format for Date, example:

```
Transaction Date = 
FORMAT(DATE(
YEAR([Transaction_Date]),
MONTH([Transaction_Date]),
DAY([Transaction_Date])
), "Short Date")
```